# How to patch data on FIREBASE through POSTMAN if authotization is needed

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, postman

I created an android app that connect to firebase, i need to update the data through REST api and due to security, i set the rules of firebase to

```
"sensor": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null"
}
```

i am testing on POSTMAN but i found that i cannot patch the data after i applied the rules, i have tried adding auth value as parameter or added to header, but none of it work.
[image]

Firebase keep return me `"error": "Could not parse auth token."` or `"error": "Permission denied"`, can anyone share the right way to access firebase with authentication way??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the you're not authentication when calling Firebase from Postman. Have a look at the Firebase documentation on authenticating for a REST request: [reference docs for auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/), [database docs for authenticating REST calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth)

Comment: Too complicated, bunch of token need to obtain but no example or demo, is there any better explanation?

Comment: Ok, i finally get the ID TOKEN from android studio and apply it on postman, the data is successfully send to the firebase, but the documentation say then ID token will expire soon, so i have to find another way to access the firebase

Comment: ID Tokens needs to be refreshed hourly. If that is a concern for you, you might want to have a look at session cookies (where you have some control over their expiration): https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies

Comment: Using Google OAuth2 access token will not have such issue right?? i'm stuck at the 'new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");' android studio keep return me filenotfound exception